# Visual Studio 2017 not recognising errors in code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I just installed the Python development workload for VS 2017 but the editor shows none of the red squiggly underlining for syntax errors that I'm used to seeing with C# on VS, nor any entries in the error list. If I try to run the code with errors, it warns me there are errors in the code but does not specify what they until exceptions are thrown from running.

I've tried reinstalling the workload and looked through every available option under the Tools/Options tab but can find nothing about syntax errors. Any fixes detailed for earlier versions of VS no longer seem to apply, what am I missing?

Comment: Are you positive that the tools you're using support that type of underlining?  Can you point to documentation that suggests that this is a feature?  Side note: this is out-of-the-box behavior for PyCharm, if this is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Yes the tools definitely support this, documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/vs-tutorial-01-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem using the simplest project from the [VS Python tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/vs-tutorial-01-02).

The fix was to upgrade from VS 15.4.1 to 15.5.

Walt

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same thing happen to me. Though this was actually with a C# application. I noticed Visual Studios stopped detecting the errors after adding a few NuGet references and doing some manual modifications of the project files. I noticed that this was only happening on this one project. All the other projects I worked on did not seem to have the same issue.

I was able to get it to start working again by creating a new project, moving my code over, and adding the references back one by one. For this situation, it looked as if a corrupt project file or bad reference was to blame even though the project would compile and run correctly.

Does this issue exist in other programming languages/projects?